# grid search hyperparameters for an image classification model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

## Overview

Ok, so I have tried to use `scikit-learn` to **grid search** hyperparameters for an image classification model in Keras. I have been told this is not possible; however, when I ran the code I am about to show you it yielded something that looks like what I was expecting.

So, If it is not possible to use scikit-learn to grid search hyperparameters for an image classification model then why did I did I get the corresponding output and how do you grid search hyperparameters  for an image classification model in Keras?

In advance I want to thank you for reading this and for helping.

## Code

```py
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

def create_model():
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
        model.add(Dense(44, activation='softmax'))
        # compile model
        opt = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
        model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.0)
dataset = datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset_dog_breeds/train/', class_mode='categorical')

X, Y = dataset.next()

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)

batch_size = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
epochs = [10, 50, 100]
param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=1, cv=3)
grid_result = grid.fit(X, Y)
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

## Output

```
Best: 0.093750 using {'batch_size': 40, 'epochs': 100}
0.031250 (0.043178) with: {'batch_size': 10, 'epochs': 10}
0.000000 (0.000000) with: {'batch_size': 10, 'epochs': 50}
0.062500 (0.045383) with: {'batch_size': 10, 'epochs': 100}
0.062500 (0.045383) with: {'batch_size': 20, 'epochs': 10}
0.031250 (0.043178) with: {'batch_size': 20, 'epochs': 50}
0.062500 (0.045383) with: {'batch_size': 20, 'epochs': 100}
0.000000 (0.000000) with: {'batch_size': 40, 'epochs': 10}
0.062500 (0.042137) with: {'batch_size': 40, 'epochs': 50}
0.093750 (0.004214) with: {'batch_size': 40, 'epochs': 100}
0.062500 (0.086356) with: {'batch_size': 60, 'epochs': 10}
0.031250 (0.043178) with: {'batch_size': 60, 'epochs': 50}
0.062500 (0.092702) with: {'batch_size': 60, 'epochs': 100}
0.000000 (0.000000) with: {'batch_size': 80, 'epochs': 10}
0.000000 (0.000000) with: {'batch_size': 80, 'epochs': 50}
0.000000 (0.000000) with: {'batch_size': 80, 'epochs': 100}
0.000000 (0.000000) with: {'batch_size': 100, 'epochs': 10}
0.031250 (0.043178) with: {'batch_size': 100, 'epochs': 50}
0.000000 (0.000000) with: {'batch_size': 100, 'epochs': 100}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is *possible* to use grid search for hyperparameter optimization, even with neural networks. However, for complex problems (involving hundreds of thousands of parameters and large data sets), it is simply not *feasible*.

When you have a problem where training takes anywhere from hours to days, exhaustive grid search is extremely inefficient, and you will likely do better tuning hyperparameters on your own.

In conclusion, your result is probably perfectly valid - it's just that grid search does not scale very well when used with neural networks.

Answer (score 0):

Grid search is not preferred for neural networks as the parameters tend to depend on the type of data and the model. Moreover, they take a large amount of computation and time. However, you still can try as long as you usecase is small.

But ideally batchsize should depend on the GPU/CPU computational resource that you have and epochs should be calculated based on the loss curve to avoid overfitting. Grid searching for these two parameters randomnly is not efficient nor productive. Try with other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of doing a grid search in a coarse-to-fine way. For instance, batch sizes of 16, 32, 64 and 128 would be meaningful. Searching over the number of epochs, not so much, because clearly, the more you train the better your training error might get (unless, it converges, of course). I'd recommend you just fix this in the beginning to whatever you deem ideal.

When doing a grid search over learning rate or learning rate decay or anything else, first do a coarse search and plot those in a heatmap-like graph with x-axis as learning rate or y-axis as decay. The heat axis should be your validation accuracy. Inspect it visually, after which, you can do a finer search over the values you found!